How can I Use MaterialLocalizations inside an enum in Flutter?
I have the following enum definition:
enum WeekStartsOn {
    sunday, monday;

    static WeekStartsOn fromString(String s) => switch (s.toLowerCase()) {
        "sunday" => sunday,
        "monday" => monday,
        _ => <<default>>
    };

    String toDisplayName() => switch (this) {
        WeekStartsOn.sunday => 'Sunday',
        WeekStartsOn.monday => 'Monday',
    };
}

I would like the <<default>> to be whatever is the correct day based on user's locale. However, I can't use MaterialLocalizations.of(context).firstDayOfWeekIndex == 0 ? monday : sunday inside of the enum because I lack context, and obtaining a context object doesn't seem like a straightforward thing. I assume localization settings belong to the global context, and I assume there should be a method along the lines of getGlobalContext(). Instead all I'm finding is convoluted tutorials about modifying the MaterialApp class, using navigatorKeys and other convoluted ideas I don't think I should be dealing with just to get a system setting. So, how do I achieve my goal of getting system localized first day of week index in my enum without all this architectural craziness?

I think the only possible way would be to use the context.

Until you find better solution, I would share my solution with context.
I would refactor the code to pass the locale context and implement a helper function that can access the context and return the WeekStartsOn.
So, the enum would look like this:
enum WeekStartsOn {
    sunday, monday;

    static WeekStartsOn fromString(String s, BuildContext context) {
        // Fallback to locale-based day if string is unrecognized
        return switch (s.toLowerCase()) {
            "sunday" => sunday,
            "monday" => monday,
            _ => getLocaleBasedDefault(context),
        };
    }

    String toDisplayName() => switch (this) {
        WeekStartsOn.sunday => 'Sunday',
        WeekStartsOn.monday => 'Monday',
    };

    static WeekStartsOn getLocaleBasedDefault(BuildContext context) {
        // Fetches the default week start day based on the locale
        final firstDayOfWeekIndex = MaterialLocalizations.of(context).firstDayOfWeekIndex;
        return firstDayOfWeekIndex == 0 ? sunday : monday;
    }
}

and inside your widget you may try to pass the context:
WeekStartsOn getWeekStartDay(String day, BuildContext context) {
    return WeekStartsOn.fromString(day, context);
}

and integrate it in UI:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WeekStartsOn startOfWeek = getWeekStartDay("unknown", context);
    return Text('Week starts on: ${startOfWeek.toDisplayName()}');
}

Maybe, there is a better approach for this issue, but I would give this a shot until you find better global context approach.
